# PHP - HTML: Selecting table header value

Tags: php, html

Lets say I have a table with 3 columns and 3 rows. 
The final two rows contain checkboxes. 
This table is inside a form. 
 I wish to send to my controller function all the checkboxes that I checked according to the specific days.

```
Monday     | Tuesday      | Wednesday
--------------------------------------
| checkbox | checkbox [x] | checkbox     |
--------------------------------------
| checkbox | checkbox     | checkbox     |
```

I want to be able to know which checkbox I checked from which specific column.
 How can I grab the appropriate column value.

For example, if I check the checkbox of the 2st row 2nd column, I also want to grab the value of my header which would be Tuesday.

Comment: Did you check by using id attribute?

Comment: This is an algorithm for me at the moment. No coding was done

Comment: Oh. I understood.

Comment: What u can do, at the time of creating the whole table in client side u can add some custome attribute like ```row```, ```coloumn```, ```day```. Then when user click on an any checkbox get the respective attributes data by javascript.  Ex - ```<input row=1 col=2 day=tus type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">Car``` Hope u got my point.

Answer (score 0):

You have two opions
1-The first to give the checkbox speical name 
So when you submit the form that contain the checkbox
You can knowif it was checked or not by check the result of post or get form

2- the second option to give the check box speical value and you can check the value of returned checkobx after submit the form

Answer (score 0):

You can add an array syntax to the name attribute of you checkbox element.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="dates[]" value="2017-05-01">
```

If you submit your form to your controller you will get an array with the name day which containts all checked dates.

```
<?php
    // contains all checked dates
    var_dump($_POST['dates']);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not final solution but you can do like that.

```
<?php
$location[][];
 for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
// tr invoke
       for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
     //td invoke checkbox value and location
            if(checkboxchecked){
             $location = checked[i][j];         
            }

    }
}
 ?>
```